# Enable Mic in Wine ? (Alsa/Pulseaudio)

Tags: wine, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm not able to make a mic work with wine-1.7.30
(the mic is the integrated mic in my pc and works fine with other applications )

I found some suggestions but they **don't seem to work**.
Anyone manage to fix this bug ?

**Reference:**

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960599
- http://alessandromuratore.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/how-to-make-the-microphone-work-in-rosetta-stone-under-ubuntu/

Comment: What Mic is it? Wine doesent Support USB.

Comment: The mic is the integrated one in my labtop.
I'm tring to use it in r. stone with wine

Comment: @prophecy201 I've managed to use a Microsoft Lifecam USB webcam's microphone in Rosetta Stone using Wine. So I think that your comment is somewhat invalid then... I've previously upvoted it but finally succeeded in proving it false. :)

Comment: To answer the original question: try using the `WINENOPULSE=1` option when you create the winebottle. I also used playonlinux with wine.

Comment: Is your mic working in Ubuntu (when not using wine)?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using. I ask since Wine 1.5 is not supported/default on Ubuntu since a couple of versions ago. If you are not using a supported Ubuntu version and an upgraded Wine (Like 1.6 or 1.7) then you will have many problems getting an answer.

Comment: I have updated the question ( it is an old question but the problem is still present with last wine )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Masu *WINENOPULSE=1* parameters fix the issue.

*There should be a way to make this setting as default in wine but I cannot find it right now.*

For the moment I'm using a manual approach:

```
env WINENOPULSE=1 wine YOUR_PROGRAM.exe
```

Or you can add it to the launcher:

Taking care that Wine launchers are stored in:  `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/`
You just have to edit the program launcher and add `WINENOPULSE=1` to the exec line.

So for Rosetta Stone the launcer will be changes as the following one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Rosetta Stone TOTALe
Exec=env WINENOPULSE=1 WINEPREFIX="/home/fra/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/fra/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/fra/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Rosetta\\ Stone/Rosetta\\ Stone\\ TOTALe/Rosetta\\ Stone\\ TOTALe.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=C722_RosettaStoneTOTALe.0
```

Comment: not work on wine 1.8

Comment: it was 2yrs ago and I am not using the mic/wine anymore ... If you find a solution please update the above answer or add your answer to this question thx.

Answer (score 3):

Change the default audio in Wine to Alsa only.
You can change it via winetricks:
`Select the default wineprefix` -> `Change settings` -> Check `sound=alsa`

An answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77210/how-to-change-the-default-audio-in-wine-to-alsa-only) shows how to do that using pictures.